# Javascript using native browser authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, digest-authentication

I am currently developing a web-application using Angular2 with TypeScript (if that matters).
This application has to communicate with a webserver, which is asking for a digest authentication.
Until now i was using the native login prompt of the browsers, which is automatically showing, when the server returns a "401 unauthorized". The browser only asks for authentication once and automatically uses this username and password for future requests. So I don't have to take care about the authentication, the browser does everything for me.
Unfortunately now i have to create a custom login screen, as i have to implement some default actions, such as "register" or "reset passwort", which are ususally accessible from that screen.
As digest authentication is quite complex and the browser would allready do all the complex things for me I would like to continue using the browsers functionality, but without using it's login prompt.
So is it possible to use the browsers authentication functionality?
If it is possible, how can I set the username and the password it should use?

**EDIT:**
As someone wanted to close this question as "to broad", i'll try to add some more detail.
The web-application gets data from a restful webservice. This webservice requires digest authentication and responds with a 401, if you are using a wrong username or password.
As mentioned above, the browser automatically shows a login prompt, if he gets a 401 error. If you enter a valid login, the browser caches those values somewhere and automatically sets them for every future request.
Now i basicly want to replace the login prompt and programatically set the values the browser should use for the login.
I hope this helps to make the question clear.

Comment: So what is the login you are using? HTAccess?

Comment: Currently i am using the browsers native login prompt

Comment: And where is the login going to verify that the user is valid?

Comment: This is server side. I basicly query data from a rest server. To get this data you have to authenticate yourself using digest authentication. So a wrong user/password results in another 401 error

Comment: @epascarello i edited the question, i hope it is clear enough now :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to write a `HTTP` decorator to intercept response code 401. Afterwards you add the `Authentication` header and replay the request.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

    /**
     * intercept request
     * @param {Observable<Response>} observable to use
     * @param {string} url to request
     * @returns {Observable<Response>} return value
     * @private
     */
    private _intercept(observable: Observable<Response>, url: string): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 401) {

                // add custom header
                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('Authentication', '<HEADER>');

                // replay request with modified header
                return this.get(url, new RequestOptions({
                    headers: headers
                });

            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        });
    };

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param {ConnectionBackend} backend to use
     * @param {RequestOptions} defaultOptions to use
     * @returns {void} nothing
     */
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    };

    /**
     * get request
     * @param {string} url to request
     * @param {RequestOptionsArgs} options to use
     * @returns {Observable<Response>} return value
     */
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this._intercept(super.get(url, options), url);
    };

}
```

What didn’t worked for me yet is determining correct responses as there was a bug filed against Angular2 (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9355), which was merged just a few days before.

You have to increment the request counter for each valid request following the first successful one.

Maybe somebody else can show up with a working solution.